# Swift: async execution in series + array of closures + escaping

Tags: swift, asynchronous, closures

I have a few async function which I'd like to run in series to avoid "callback hell" and simplify things I've written the following helper structure:

```
typealias AsyncCallback = (Bool) -> Void
typealias AsyncFunction = (AsyncCallback) -> Void

public struct AsyncHelpers {
    public static func series(_ functions: [AsyncFunction], _ callback: @escaping AsyncCallback) {
        var index = 0
        var completed: AsyncCallback? = nil

        completed = { success in
            if success == false { callback(false); return }

            index += 1
            if index < functions.count {
                functions[index](completed!)
                return
            }

            callback(true)
        }

        functions[index](completed!)
    }
}

AsyncHelpers.series([
    { callback in
        // do async stuff
        callback(true)
    }, { callback in
        // then do async stuff
        callback(true)
    }
]) { callback in
    // when all completed
}
```

I can set the @escaping attribute for completion handler, but when I try to apply this attribute to [AsyncFunction] compilator fails with this error: "@escaping attribute only applies to function types". Should I mark these closured as escaping in other way, please?

What is lifecycle of index variable, can I use it inside completed closure without any problem?

Comment: Yes compilator fails because `functions` is __array__ of function, but `@escaping` attribute only applies to __function__ types

Comment: You will also get this warning when using a `typealias` for your closures.  I wish it wasn't true, but it is.

Comment: Okay, so actually the **series** function may work as expected. The index variable will be copied to heap and closure will keep a strong reference to this variable. I don't need to set an attribute for the individual element 
 in **functions** because swift will keep strong reference for array too (and all elements). Is that correct?